# Coordination change for integrals and determinant of the jacobian matrix

Tags: calculus, integration

so I am currently learning about flow integrals and my book had an example which confused me. (Example 1) As you see, in Example 1, they don't care about the determinant of the jacobian of the coordination change. They just switch coordinats without transforming the integral properly. In Example 2 they actually use the determinant of the jacobian of the coordination change.

Let me make two examples:

**Example 1:**
Calculate the flow of $v=(0,0,1-z)$ from bottom up through

$$H=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3 | x^2+y^2+z^2=1, z>0\}$$

*Parametrization:*

$$\Phi:[0,2\pi]\times[0,\pi/2]\to\mathbb R^3, \quad (u,v)\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}\sin v\cos u \\ \sin v\sin u\\ cos v\end{pmatrix}$$

*Normal vector:*
$$\Phi_v\times \Phi_u = \begin{pmatrix}\sin^2 v\cos u \\ \sin v\sin^2 u\\ \sin v \cos v\end{pmatrix}$$

*Flow integraL:*
$\int_H v\cdot ndo = \int_0^{2\pi}du\int_0^{\pi/2}dv \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1-\cos v\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\sin^2 v\cos u \\ \sin v\sin^2 u\\ \sin v \cos v\end{pmatrix}$

$=2\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}dv \sin v \cos v(1-\cos v)$

$=2\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}dv \sin v \cos v - 2\pi \int_0^{\pi/2}dv \sin v \cos^2 v=...=\pi/3$

**Example 2:** We want to calculate the flow of $v=(xz,z,y)$ through the unit ball, centered around $O=(0,0,0)$ using Gauss's Divergene Theorem.

We have to calculate $\int_S v\cdot n do = \int_{B_1} div(v) d\mu$

$div(v)=z$

We use spherical coordinates. So: $dxdydz=r^2dr\sin\phi d\phi d\varphi$

$\int_s v \cdot n do = \int_{B_1} zd\mu = \int_0^1 r^2 dr \int_0^\pi \sin\phi d\phi \int_0^{2\pi}d\varphi \cdot r\cos \phi=...=0$

Comment: The jacobian is absorbed into $\Phi_v\times \Phi_u$. If you go through the derivation of the formula, you will see where it arises

Comment: Yeah I just went through everything again and the normal vector$n$ absorbs it. So if we calculate a given flow using Gauss's Divergence Theorem, we actually have to take it into account but if we use the normal definition, we don't - right?